# How to handle uninitialized navigation ref in React Navigation v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Context: I'm using v4 of React Navigation. I have a `<PushNotificationHandler />` and `<DynamicLinksHandler />` that is outside my navigators. These components use `NavigationService` using the `ref` provided from `createAppContainer` to navigate.

In v5 you have an `onReady` prop to check to see if the app is ready to be navigated for your NavigationService to use to avoid app crashes (see [handling initialization docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization)). But in v4 it doesn't have that prop and I don't know how to avoid navigations that happen before the app navigators mount i.e. within a DynamicLinks or PushNotification component. Any suggestions?

v5 docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization

v4 docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization

NavigationService:

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation'

export default class NavigationService {
  static navigator

  static initialize(navigatorRef) {
    NavigationService.navigator = navigatorRef
  }

  static isNavigatorDefined() {
    // App hasn't mounted so don't navigate
    if (!NavigationService.navigator) {
      // TODO: We need to push these navigations into a queue and navigate once the app mounts
      console.error('NavigationService.navigator is undefined')
      return false
    }
    return true
  }

  static navigate(routeName, params) {
    if (!NavigationService.isNavigatorDefined()) {
      return
    }

    // Perform navigation if the app has mounted
    NavigationService.navigator.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName,
        params,
      })
    )
  }
...
}
```

AppMain:

```
...

const AppMain = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <>
      <DynamicLinksHandler />
      <PushNotificationHandler />
      <AppNavigator
        ref={(navigatorRef) => NavigationService.initialize(navigatorRef)}
        onNavigationStateChange={() => handleNavigationStateChange}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default AppMain
```

DynamicLinksHandler (snippet):

```
...
// In a listener for dynamic links
NavigationService.navigate('GroupHome', {
          group: {
            id: groupId,
          },
        })
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the ref 'navigatorRef' to others components and if !ref.current, ref is not ready.
I do this with some svg to manipulate the dom of the svg. On the first render ref.current is null so return. On the seconde render, the ref is set so go on.
You can olso create a const isReady = ref.current ? true : false and do {if (isReady && <PushNotificationHandler.../>